# Is it possible to pass an @Input value to app.component in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I'm using ASP.Net to render my Angular 2 app, and the only RAZOR page I have is the _Layout.cshtml and I would love to be able to pass some init data from RAZOR into my bootstrapped component, but it doesn't seem to work.

In my _Layout.cshtml, I have the following:

```
<my-app test="abc"></my-app>
```

and in my app.component.ts, I have:

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: "<div id='mainBody'>Test:{{test}}</div>",
    directives: [MenuBarComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent {
    @Input() test;
}
```

My test variable is blank.  Is there a different way to do this, or is it just not possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337185/passing-asp-net-server-parameters-to-angular-2-app/37384405#37384405

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not possible to use inputs for main components (bootstrapped ones). You need to get the attribute directly from the DOM:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: "<div id='mainBody'>Test:{{test}}</div>",
  directives: [MenuBarComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {
    this.test = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('test');
  }
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to create a global javascript object in the _Layout, how would I access that within my TypeScript constructor?

Comment: You would add it as a provider in your NgModule via an [InjectionToken](http://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#injectiontok‌​en)