# How to read the property of a application selector at the time of initialization?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my start page, it is rendered on the backend (instead of `'propval'` there will be a variable containing the json-configuration):

```
<%- include('template/head'); %>
<application [userdata]='"propval"'>
    Loading...
</application>
<%- include('template/foot'); %>
```

This is my component that handles the 'application' selector:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'application',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    providers:[
        ProgressBar
    ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    public userdata;

    constructor(public progressBar :ProgressBar, private router: Router) {
        console.log("constructor",this.userdata);
    }

    public async ngOnInit() {
        console.log("ngOnInit",this.userdata);
    }

}
```

As a result, in the console I get:

```
constructor undefined
ngOnInit undefined
```

How to read `userdata` property? Perhaps this is not will done in `AppComponent`, since `application` selector is not rendered inside the `app.component.html`. `application` selector rendered on the backend.

Comment: Did you tried to add an input for this property?   @Input() userdata;

Comment: @galvan Yes, it did not work

Comment: Would this help ?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382892/is-it-possible-to-pass-an-input-value-to-app-component-in-angular-2

Comment: @Vega No, it didn't work either.

Comment: You can't feed properties into your app component like this, a config type object should be provided in a service and injected into the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [question Vega shared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382892/is-it-possible-to-pass-an-input-value-to-app-component-in-angular-2) points out that bootstrap and entry components cannot use input bindings. (I did not find the source code, but by reasoning that an entry component should not have a parent, it makes sense that they would not use input bindings.)

The accepted answer uses `ElementRef` to get the data attribute, that approach should work for your case as well.

```
import {ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

constructor(private _ref: ElementRef) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.userdata = this._ref.nativeElement.getAttribute('userdata');
}
```

[Sample plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/eMRNHnhXWCyyw6Uju0Fu?p=preview)

Other solutions that might work for you or others: configure an `InjectionToken` ([doc](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#injectiontoken)) or a use a service.